# php mail() two copies sent

Tags: php, email

I have a simple message that I send using php mail().
The code used:

```
//recipient info
$to = "$bookernavn <$mail>";
$from = "Visens Venner Hillerød <booking@eksample.dk>";
$subject = "Kvittering - $a_titel - ". date("j/n - Y",$a_dato);

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: $from" . "\r\n";

// now lets send the email. 
mail($to, $subject, $mailmsg, $headers); }
```

For some strange reason two mails are sent each time...
Sometimes with several minutes in between...
Any ideas?

Comment: You do realise you have a `Bcc` header in there right? One mail goes to `$to`, the other to `$from`. If they are the same, two mails arrive on the same address.

Comment: They are not the same :-)  I just want to store a copy of the receipt sent to the booker... so thats not it - but good guess :-)

Comment: I see a curly brace there. Do you have perhaps more code, that makes the `mail()` call fire twice?

Comment: It is enclosed in "if(strlen($mail)>0) {" ... that's all

Answer (score 1):

You don't check to see if the form has been submitted so a browser refresh will send the form data again and cause the mail to be sent again. This also happens when a user presses the back button.

After the email is sent you need to do a 303 redirect to prevent the re-submission. You can redirect to the same page if you'd like.

This is called the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

```
mail(...);
header('Location: /some-page-php', true, 303);
exit;
```

Comment: It is a page that recieves a form - and I have: " header('location:kvittering.php') " a few lines down. I will try to add "true , 303" and "exit;" to it :-)

Comment: This also applies to using the back button so this still applies

Comment: Good to know... but the above form consequently sends two mails - also with out going back. So that is not the current problem

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to prevent this from happening is to use POST method instead of GET for the form.

```
<form method="post">



if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
```

and at the end of the mail code use a redirect that will send the browser to load using a GET method.

Not only you can then redirect your user to a OK page "mail was sent" or a error page "sorry there was a mistake, please try again", a refresh of that page open by the browser will only send a GET, not triggering the send mail function

```
if (empty($errors)) {
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/mail_OK.html');
  exit;
} else {
  // passing data to the "error/retry" page
  $info = array(
    'msg' => $msg,
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'name' => $_POST['name']
    // etc...
  )
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/mailform.php?'.http_build_query($info));
  exit;
}
```

in your form you can retrieve those info

```
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Naam" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']); ?>">
```

Comment: the problem with changing it to post is that, i will get a pop up when I refresh the page.. and it still sends a second time :(

Comment: You didn't read all the way... header('Location: ...') will turn the browser to a GET, so only when user press the submit button (or press enter) the browser will do a POST.  The response to the post will be a redirect to a GET so next refresh will be a GET. (I notice that I've forgotten to put an exit after the header)